# Play Framework: how to refer to a template in another sub-project

Tags: scala, playframework

Given the following multi-project Play application...

```
+ myApp
    + app
    + conf
    + modules
        + myModule1
        |    + app
        |    |  + controllers
        |    |  + models
        |    |  + views
        |    |      + main.scala.html
        |    + conf
        + myModule2
             + app
             |  + controllers
             |  + models
             |  + views
             |      + index.scala.html
             + conf
```

... how do I call `myModule1/app/views/main.scala.html` from `myModule2/app/views/index.scala.html`? Is it possible to define a layout template once and then reuse it in all sub-projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you folders sub projects or modules? In both cases you will need to edit the `build.Scala`.

In your case I would define a `Core` project and this core project will be referenced from the other subprojects:

```
val codePrj = play.Project(
  "App-myCore", appVersion, coreDeps, path = file("modules/myCore")
)

val myModule1 = play.Project(
  "App-myModule1", appVersion, moduleOneDeps, path = file("modules/myModule1")
).dependsOn(codePrj)

val myModule2 = play.Project(
  "App-myModule2", appVersion, moduleTwoDeps, path = file("modules/myModule2")
).dependsOn(codePrj)
```

Then your main project should glue everything together:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, mainDeps).settings(
).dependsOn(myModule1, myModule2)
```